# Question about positive and negative parts $f^+ = \frac{|f| + f}{2}, f^- = \frac{|f| - f}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For an extended real-valued function $f$, do we have the representation $\displaystyle f^+ = \frac{|f| + f}{2}$ and $\displaystyle f^- = \frac{|f| - f}{2}$? At least it seems to say so on the Wikipedia page. But doesn't this not make sense if say $f$ is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$? E.g. if $f$ is $-\infty$ then then the numerator of $f^+$ is $+\infty - \infty$ which is undefined. And similary if $f$ is $+\infty$ then the numerator of $f^-$ is undefined.

Comment: Your observation is correct. We cannot write $f^{+}=\frac {|f|+f} 2$ for extended real valued functions.